# Type UITableView does not conform to prototcol IntervalType

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I upgraded to xcode 6 beta 5. It appeared a new error: **Type UITableView does not conform to protocol IntervalType.**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    switch tableView{
    case tableViewPopular: // ERROR
        println("tableViewPopular")
        return 1
    case tableViewSearch: // ERROR
        print("tableViewSearch ")
        println("sceneKeys.count --> \(sceneKeys.count)")
        return sceneKeys.count
    case self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView:
        println("SearchDisplayController")
        return 1
    default:
        println("default")
        return 0
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: How are tableViewPopular and tableViewSearch defined?

Comment: **@IBOutlet var tableViewPopular:UITableView!** and
**@IBOutlet var tableViewSearch:UITableView!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you unwrap all the `tableView`s explicitly:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    switch tableView{
    case tableViewPopular!:
        println("tableViewPopular")
        return 1
    case tableViewSearch!:
        print("tableViewSearch ")
        return 2
    case self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView!:
        println("SearchDisplayController")
        return 3
    default:
        assert(false, "This should not happen!")
        return 0
    }
}
```

This seems a bit strange to me, because all those properties are already declared as
implicitly unwrapped, so this could be a Swift bug.

Comment: @marcobonny88: I tested it in a table view controller where I had to specify the override keyword. You can just remove it if your don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 if tableView == tableViewPopular
{
// Statements
}
else if tableView ==  tableViewSearch
{
// statements
}
```